# Displaying tif files in jupyter notebook vie ipywidgets

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tiff, ipywidgets

I am trying to display .tif images using the ipywidgets in jupyter-notebooks. The below code works for .png and .jpg files

```
from ipywidgets import Image
png_image_path = r"C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Work\Exercises\images\000000000.png"
file = open(png_image_path, "rb")
im = file.read()

Image(
    value=im,
    width=300,
    height=400,
)

type(im) # <class 'bytes'>
```

The ipywidget from the above code renders the desired image. For reading a `tif` file I am using `gdal`.

```
img = gdal.Open(tif_img_path).ReadAsArray()
print(img.shape) # (3, 1024, 1024)
print(img.transpose(1,2, 0).shape) # (1024, 1024, 3)

type(img.transpose(1,2,0).tobytes()) # <class 'bytes'>

Image(
    value=img.transpose(1,2,0).tobytes(),
    width=300,
    height=400,
)
```

I get the following output, the image is not properly displayed in the ipywidget

[image: I get the following output]

Comment: I don't use jupyter or its widgets but... in the first example you are passing the PNG-encoded image with its PNG header, date, bits/pixel, colour type and compressed pixel data. In the GDAL case, you are passing uncompressed pixels with no header... very different things.

Comment: I tried the 1st approach for the tif files as well, but it didn't worked. Then I saw that the type of im which is passed in the Image widgets is bytes, so I thought reading image as bytes can work for tif image.

Comment: Try printing `im[:40]` and you'll see `/x89PNG` and `IHDR` which is how a PNG header looks on disk. Do the same for your TIFF and you'll see no TIFF header (starts with `II` or `MM`).

Comment: There may be another way to do it, but you *could* use **ImageMagick** to make a TIFF into a PNG with `magick input.tif output.png`. Or you could use **OpenCV** `imencode()` in Python to take your GDAL-read Numpy array into an *"in-memory"* PNG.

Comment: `imencode()` example... https://stackoverflow.com/a/66036559/2836621

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. If you could post/write what you suggested in the comments as an answer in just 2-3 lines, I will upvote the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Cool - glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you just do `file.read()` on the PNG image implies to me that Jupyter widgets expect a PNG or JPEG-encoded image, with a header and compressed pixel data.

If you open your TIFF with GDAL you will have a Numpy array, so you will need to encode it into an *"in-memory"* PNG or JPEG before passing to Jupyter widgets. You can do that with **OpenCV** like this:

```
import cv2

# Open TIFF image into Numpy array
img = gdal.Open(tif_img_path).ReadAsArray()

# Encode into in-memory PNG for Jupyter
_, PNG = cv2.imencode('.png', img)
```

As you rightly note in the comments, **OpenCV** uses BGR ordering so you would need to reverse the order of the colour channels with:

```
RGBimage =  cv2.cvtColor(BGRimage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

---

As an alternative to introducing the **OpenCV** dependency and its weird channel ordering, you could use **PIL/Pillow** which uses regular RGB ordering. In that case, you would convert a Numpy array you got from GDAL into a PNG with:

```
from io import BytesIO

im = ... read from GDAL ...

# Write Numpy array to in-memory PNG
membuf = BytesIO()
Image.fromarray(im).save(membuf, format="png") 

... you can now use membuf.getvalue()
```

---

Note also, that in general TIFFs may contain float or float64 values that cannot be expressed in an 8-bit JPEG, so you may need to re-scale your data to fit the smaller range.

Comment: just a small comment - opencv reads image in BRG format, to convert the image to RGB format we need to do inmem_img = cv2.imencode('.png', cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))[1].tobytes()

Comment: Hi Anurag. I updated my answer to clarify a couple of things.