# Equivalent for converting numpy array to bytes

Tags: python, arrays, image, api, encoding

I have the following code for converting an image (from path, `img_path: str`) to bytes (`b64 encoded`):

```
with open(img_path, "rb") as img_file:
  out_file = base64.b64encode(img_file.read())
```

This is required to send it to a Microsoft Azure Python SDK service.
I want to write the equivalent code for doing this given a numpy array `arr`.

I tried the following:

```
arr = cv2.imread(img_path)
out_file = base64.b64encode(arr.tobytes())
```

But it failed. In particular, the actual result is totally different. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your first `out_file` is a base64-encoded version of a JPEG/PNG-encoded (compressed) image with metadata such as copyright, EXIF. Your second `out_file` is just a base64 encoded version of the decompressed pixels themselves because `cv2.imread()` decompresssed the JPEG into an *"in-memory"* representation of the pixels. The latter doesn't even contain the image height or width - it's just pixels.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, is it possible to  have an equivalent representation for a numpy array? Or shall I have to save it, and load it as the former example?

Comment: You can use `cv2.imencode()` to compress your image (as held in a Numpy array) into an *"in-memory"* JPEG/PNG. Then base64-encode the result. Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66036559/2836621